# Error con php artisan migrate (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo un problema al ejecutar el comando php artisan migrate en la terminal de laravel, Si al .env le agrego contraseña me sale el siguiente error en la terminal:

```html
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fechas and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\laragon\www\FechasVencimiento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file")
      C:\laragon\www\FechasVencimiento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=fechas", "root", "12345", [])
      C:\laragon\www\FechasVencimiento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Pero si le quito la contraseña, sale este error:

```html
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fechas and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\laragon\www\FechasVencimiento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
      C:\laragon\www\FechasVencimiento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=fechas", "root", "", [])
      C:\laragon\www\FechasVencimiento\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

He buscado bastante acerca del error pero no me funcionan ninguna de las soluciones que dan y no se a que se deba el error, de verdad espero que me puedan ayudar ya que no puedo avanzar en mi proyecto sin antes migrar las tablas, muchas gracias.

Comment: esto debería funcionarte
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831183/error-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authenticatio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831183/error-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authenticatio) Un saludo.

Comment: Bro pudiste corregir este error, igualmente ya modifique el .env y nada

Comment: No puedes migrar porque tu aplicación no puede conectarse a la BD, esto suele ser por errores de las credenciales o host mal configurado, en tu caso una version de mysql muy antigua:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please ...` debería resolverse instalando 5.6 en adelande o mariadb

Answer (score 0):

Cambia "host" en el archivo /app/config/database.php y en el archivo .env cambia ”localhost" a ”127.0.0.1”. Eso debería resolver tu problema